# What are the best on-line tools for learning french

Tags: ressources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Free online resources for beginner course](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/509/free-online-resources-for-beginner-course)

I've been studying French for about 9 months and I've found the following on-line tools helpful.

> [News in slow French](http://www.newsinslowfrench.com/)
>
> [Ma France](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/french/mafrance/flash/#) (BBC)

What other high quality on-line tools are available?

A related question: [Free online resources for beginner course](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/509/free-online-resources-for-beginner-course)

Comment: As you said, this is a duplicate question. You should edit your question with any extra information that would differentiate it.

Comment: I think we'd like an up-to-date list of both free _and_ pay services.  Neither of my excellent resources are listed in the other similar question.  Perhaps you can collate these answers.  Thanks!