# References for self-teaching french language

Tags: apprentissage

I want to learn french on my own. I don't know anything about french and i want to start from the beginning. I want some books or references.

Comment: Welcome to FL&U! This question is off-topic. In order to find resources, please refer to related questions (you'll see a list of them on the right), and if you don't find anything that matches what you need, you might want to try to ask in the [chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette).

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: Even though too general resource requests are not particularly welcome, as far as I know [they have been on-topic](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/127/are-resources-for-learning-french-on-topic-les-demandes-de-ressources-pour-lap) since the beginning.

Comment: [Free online resources for beginner course](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/509/217)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Well, this question looked very general to me, and already covered several times before. And I couldn't see a clear answer in the meta question you linked, it looks like "OK for wiki questions on general resources, OK for user questions on specific resources, other user questions should be closed / marked as duplicate". But you're right, I shouldn't have voted to close as off-topic, I should have looked for a duplicate.